Edit modal state without server-side state management
I'm developing an app using Livewire with Laravel Breeze and have implemented a modal provided by Breeze.
It works well for adding a user, but I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to manage the state of an edit modal without server-side state management.
I know that Jetstream uses a different approach where the modal is managed by server-side Livewire, and I've tried using it for edits, but it isn't as smooth as the one based on Alpine.js with dispatch, which takes over 300ms to respond.
Is there a way to use the Breeze modal based on Alpine.js and dispatch, and only make a server request to fetch the user data when a user is clicked? Or would it be better to use Axios in this case? Any help would be appreciated.
